# [Help]How to Initializing android Environment in Ubuntu 10.04

Tags: android, ubuntu-10.04

i am trying to install android Environment in ubuntu 10.04. for that i am using this link which is provide by google.

http://source.android.com/source/initializing.html

Still i am facing some problem

**Setting up ccache**
when in put this line in terminal i found error

[export CCACHE_DIR="path-to-your-cache-directory"]

"path-to-your-cache-directory"

here i have to put the path but who could i find that? i don't know

if someone knows any other tutorial which gives me explanation what we are trying to do so please pass that. i am just beginner in linux.

Answer (score 0):

You just have to do this if your home directory is on NFS or some other non-local filesystem.
"By default the cache will be stored in ~/.ccache. If your home directory is on NFS or some other non-local filesystem, you will want to specify the directory in your .bashrc as well."

If this isn't the case just skipt this step.

Comment: in my case i need this so i cant skip 

[exprot CCACHE_DIR=<~/.ccache.>] i use this but i get error "bash: syntax error near unexpected token `newline'" any idea what i can do for this

Comment: Is this your export command how you enter it? If not please post it. If it is your command you have a typo in export and you should use the absolute path: /home/username/.ccache and without brackets and username is your username on the system: export CCACHE_DIR=/home/username/.ccache